# Can one specify a custom force function for a force-directed layout?

Tags: d3.js, graph-layout

I want to experiment with an alternative family force functions for force-directed graph layouts.

For each node `n_i`, I can define a "force function" `f_i` such that

- `f_i ( n_i )` is identically zero; and
- `f_i ( n_j )`, where `n_i != n_j`, is the force on node `n_i` that is due to some other node `n_j`.

The net force on node `n_i` should then be the vector sum of the forces `f_i ( n_j )`, where `n_j` ranges over all other nodes<sup>1</sup>.

**Is there some way to tell d3.js to use these *custom force functions* in the layout algorithm?**

[The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) for d3.js's force-directed layout describes various ways in which its built-in force function can be tweaked, but I have not been able to find a way to specify an entirely different force function altogether, i.e. a force function that cannot be achieved by tweaking the parameters of the built-in force function.]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>IOW, no other/additional forces should act on node `n_i` besides those computed from its force function `f_i`.</sup>

Comment: You would need to create a new layout to use your custom force.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: thanks for the pointer.  I just scanned the d3.js docs, but I was not able to find any documentation on creating custom layouts.  I imagine that this involves something like `d3.layout.myLayout = function () { ... }`, but it's not at all clear to me what exactly this function should return.  IOW, I can't find any documentation on the "layout interface".  Of course, I could try to reverse-engineer the d3.js source, but my previous attempts to do this have been pretty traumatic, so I'd really prefer not to do this if possible.

Comment: There's no documentation on that I'm afraid -- you'll have to go by the source. Starting with the force layout should be pretty straightforward though as, by the sound of it, the structure of your custom layout would be very similar to that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: thanks again; I'll accept your comments as the answer if you post them as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you'll need to create your own custom layout. There's no tutorial for this that I'm aware of, but the source code for the existing force layout should be a good starting point as, by the sound of it, the structure of your custom layout would be very similar to that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Credit goes to [Shan Carter](https://bl.ocks.org/shancarter) and his [bl.ocks example](https://bl.ocks.org/shancarter/f621ac5d93498aa1223d8d20e5d3a0f4)

```js
let margin = {
  top: 100,
  right: 100,
  bottom: 100,
  left: 100
};

let width = 960,
  height = 500,
  padding = 1.5, // separation between same-color circles
  clusterPadding = 6, // separation between different-color circles
  maxRadius = 12;

let n = 200, // total number of nodes
  m = 10, // number of distinct clusters
  z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20),
  clusters = new Array(m);

let svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('width', width)
  .append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

let nodes = d3.range(200).map(() => {
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
    radius = Math.sqrt((i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random())) * maxRadius,
    d = {
      cluster: i,
      r: radius
    };
  if (!clusters[i] || (radius > clusters[i].r)) clusters[i] = d;
  return d;
});

let circles = svg.append('g')
  .datum(nodes)
  .selectAll('.circle')
  .data(d => d)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('r', (d) => d.r)
  .attr('fill', (d) => z(d.cluster))
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1);

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .velocityDecay(0.2)
  .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(.0005))
  .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(.0005))
  .force("collide", collide) // <<-------- CUSTOM FORCE
  .force("cluster", clustering)//<<------- CUSTOM FORCE 
  .on("tick", ticked);

function ticked() {
  circles
    .attr('cx', (d) => d.x)
    .attr('cy', (d) => d.y);
}

// Custom 'clustering' force implementation.
function clustering(alpha) {
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    var cluster = clusters[d.cluster];
    if (cluster === d) return;
    var x = d.x - cluster.x,
      y = d.y - cluster.y,
      l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
      r = d.r + cluster.r;
    if (l !== r) {
      l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
      d.x -= x *= l;
      d.y -= y *= l;
      cluster.x += x;
      cluster.y += y;
    }
  });
}
// Custom 'collide' force implementation.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.quadtree()
    .x((d) => d.x)
    .y((d) => d.y)
    .addAll(nodes);

  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    var r = d.r + maxRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding),
      nx1 = d.x - r,
      nx2 = d.x + r,
      ny1 = d.y - r,
      ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {

      if (quad.data && (quad.data !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.data.x,
          y = d.y - quad.data.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = d.r + quad.data.r + (d.cluster === quad.data.cluster ? padding : clusterPadding);
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.data.x += x;
          quad.data.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Also here is a more [in-depth](https://hi.stamen.com/forcing-functions-inside-d3-v4-forces-and-layout-transitions-f3e89ee02d12) look at the subject.